# Laravel- Trying to set the content of a PDF file conditionally from within blade.php file

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, pdf-generation

There is a feature on a Laravel/ PHP site I'm working on that allows a user to download a payment reminder letter as a PDF file- the PDF is generated based on properties belonging to the database entry that they choose to download the PDF for.

The `reminder.blade.php` file that is generated for the download originally looked like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body style="....">
    @foreach ($transaction as $transaction)
        ...
        <!-- Content of the PDF here -->
    @endforeach
</body>
```

I want to change what the PDF displays based on the number/type of `transactionItems` in the `$transaction` that is being exported to the PDF- if there is only one `transactionItem` in the `$transaction` with a `$transactionItem.currentStatusId` property value of `1010` (an ID of a particular value of the `$transactionItem.currentStatusId` field, only the first page of the PDF should be generated, otherwise, all pages should be generated (as they currently are)

To do this, I have tried to surround the `<body></body>` tags with an `@if` that checks the number of `transactionItems` in the `$transaction` that's being exported, and set the content of the PDF appropriately within each of the `@if` & `@else` statement, so the changes I made to the `reminder.blade.php` file mean it currently looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    ...
</head>
@if(($transaction->count($transaction['transactionItem']) == 1) && ($transaction['transactionItem']['currentStatusId'] == '1010'))
    <body style="....">
        @foreach ($transaction as $transaction)
            ...
            <!-- First page of PDF only -->
        @endforeach
    </body>
@else
    <body style="...">
        @foreach ($transaction as $transaction)
            ...
            <!-- Original PDF here -->
        @endforeach
    </body>
@endif
</html>
```

However, when I now export the PDF file, although the file downloads successfully, when I try to open it, I get an error that says:

> Failed to load PDF document.

Anyone have any idea why I might be getting this? I assume there's something I'm doing wrong with the `@if` statement I'm using to generate the content dynamically, but I can't see what... Can anyone point me in the right direction? How can I alter the content of the PDF generated based on the value of a field in the database, which is being used to generate the PDF?

Comment: Is `@foreach ($transaction as $transaction)` your actual code? You cannot use the same variable for the whole collection as well as the iteration variable. Anyway, your `@if()` statemnent doesn't make any sense. But to suggest a solution, we'd need more information about the data structure of your transactions.

Comment: Yes, `@foreach ($transaction as $transaction)` is the actual code in the blade.php file- that is displaying the information for each transaction item within the transaction one at a time. I want to only display one transaction item when there is a transactoin item with a `currentStatusId` with value `1010` (there will be other transaction items within the transaction at this point, but only the one with `currentStatusId` value `1010` should be displayed).

Comment: Maybe try some debugging first? Load the blade as a simple view and see if it throws any errors.

Comment: I'm pretty new to Laravel- what do you mean by load the blade as a simple view?